# ng-show/ ng-hide not responding, no console error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

So i am making a Todo App in angular js 1.x (1.6) but my ng-show and ng-hide do not work. the goal is to make a textbox appear in the todo section when you click the edit button to edit current todos, also the edit button becomes a done button so you may make the changes. however, that is not working out. the console shows no errors, and i do believe the logic correct. `

```
<div ng-controller="todoCtrl as ctrl">
      <div>
        <p>Add a Todo</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.newTodo">
        <button ng-click="ctrl.addNewTodo()">Add</button>


      </div>

        <div >
          <p>Your Todos:</p>
          <button ng-hide="ctrl.editMode" ng-click="ctrl.triggerEdit">Edit</button>
          <button ng-show="ctrl.editMode" ng-click="ctrl.triggerEdit">Done</button>
          <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="todo in ctrl.todos track by $index">
              <span ng-hide="ctrl.editMode" ng-bind="todo"></span>
              <input ng-model="todo" ng-show="ctrl.editMode" type="text"></input>
              <button ng-hide="ctrl.editMode" ng-click="ctrl.deleteTodo($index)">Delete</button>
            </li>
          </ol>

        </div>
    </div>
```

`

here is the js

```
    var app = angular.module("todoApp", []);
app.controller("todoCtrl", todoCtrl);

function todoCtrl(){
  this.editMode = false;
  this.todos = [
    "Learn Angular 1",
    "Try out exercises",
    "Visit Docs "
  ];

  this.addNewTodo = function(){
    this.todos.push(this.newTodo);
    this.newTodo = "";
  }
  this.triggerEdit = function(){
    this.editMode = !this.editMode;
  }

  this.deleteTodo = function(index){
    this.todos.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are calling the `triggerEdit()` function with parenthesis. Seems like you have missed them, give it a try

```
<button ng-hide="ctrl.editMode" ng-click="ctrl.triggerEdit()">Edit</button>
<button ng-show="ctrl.editMode" ng-click="ctrl.triggerEdit()">Done</button>
```

Comment: please excuse me as i go kms! thank you, that solved it